# SQL query for top and bottom value for a particular date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

SQL Server 2000

My Table:

```
CARDNO  CARDEVENTDATE   CARDEVENTTIME
121 20090610    025050
 121    20090611    040000
121 20090611    050000
121 20090611    020000
122 20090611    030001
122 20090611    030000
123 20090611    080000
123 20090611    100000
123 20090611    132449
123 20090611    025959
124 20090610    030000
124 20090612    030001
125 20090611    030002
125 20090612    040000
```

Cardno is Separate Table 
Cardeventdate, cardeventtime is separate table

From the above table I want to get Top Time and Bottom Time for the Particular cardeventdate and Cardno

For the 121, 20090611, Top Time is 040000, Bottom Time is 020000
For 123, 20090611, Top Time is 080000, Bottom Time is 025959 …
Like this I need.

I used Min (time) and Max (time), But it showing like this.

For CardNo – 121
Cardeventdate – 20090611
Min Time – 020000
Max Time – 040000

I don’t want to get min and Max, I need only top and Bottom (or) First and Last time value of the particular Date and Cardno.

I used this Query

```
SELECT     RowNumber = IDENTITY (int, 1, 1), CARDNO, CARDEVENTDATE, CARDEVENTTIME INTO #Table1 FROM T_CARDEVENT SELECT     t1.CARDNO, t1.CARDEVENTDATE, t1.CARDEVENTTIME  FROM #Table t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT     RowNumber = MIN(RowNumber), CARDEVENTDATE, CARDNO  FROM  #Table1 t  WHERE      (cardeventdate > 20090601) GROUP BY cardno, cardeventdate  UNION ALL  SELECT     MAX(RowNumber), CARDEVENTDATE, CARDNO FROM #Table1 t WHERE     (cardeventdate > 20090601) GROUP BY cardno, cardeventdate) t2 ON t2.rownumber = t1.rownumber
```

Output:

```
ROWNUMBER   CARDNO  CARDEVENTDATE   CARDEVENTTIME
335 0121               20090611     040000
1099    0121               20090611     050000
1100    0121               20090611     025050
336 0121               20090612     020000
337 0122               20090611     030001
338 0122               20090612     030000
339 0123               20090611     080000
1101    0123               20090611     100000
1102    0123               20090611     132449
340 0123               20090612     025959
341 0124               20090611     030000
342 0124               20090612     030001
343 0125               20090611     030002
344 0125               20090612     040000
```

So Here Row Number is created for all columns, from that how I have to take First Time and Last Time for the Particular Date.

Expecting Output

```
CARDNO  CARDEVENTDATE   CARDEVENTTIME   Expecting
0121    20090611    040000  Top Value
0121    20090611    020000  No Need
0121    20090611    025050  Bottom Value
```

……… so on

Need Query Help.

Comment: What is the order of your data? Without an order you cannot get a first or last record.

Comment: For the time, this is the order 
How can i get? plz urgent

Comment: do you have another field in this table that may help you define "first" and "last"? like IDENTITY column or TIMESTAMP/DATETIME that would correspond to your "sorting"?

Comment: Yes Time Column also there, table structure id date time, value

Comment: DATE and TIME are two different columns? what SQL DB do you use and what is the type of the TIME column?

Comment: @Jash: you are not showing everything. 1. There is no way that that input could generate that output with given query for starters. The Rownumber column isn't even present in the select. If I adjust my script for your given input, the output for 121 20090611 is 040000 and 020000.
2. In your input you have "121 20090611    020000". In your output you have "121 20090611    025050". Normally I would assume this to be a mere typing error but considering our long conversation we already had in our comments, I have stopped guessing at what you "might" mean.
Please, be as exact as you can.

Comment: @Jash, I have completely changed my answer to reflect your input table. If you copy and paste the entire script, could you confirm if it does or does not give the results you'd expect. If it does, you have to look for an error in your own input tables. If it does not, what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Lieven: Your Query Output - 

ROW NO     CARDNO CARDDATE CARDTIME

1 121 20090610 025050
2 121 20090611 040000
3 121 20090611 050000
4 121 20090611 020000
5 122 20090611 030001
6 122 20090611 030000
7 123 20090611 080000
8 123 20090611 100000
9 123 20090611 132449
10 123 20090611 025959
11 124 20090610 030000
12 124 20090612 030001
13 125 20090611 030002
14 125 20090612 040000

Comment: @Lieven: For Cardno: 121, Date: 20090611, Top Value is 040000 and Bottom Value is 020000. But it also showing the 050000. 050000 Should not show in the output. For Cardno: 123. Date:20090611, Top Value is 080000 and Bottom Value is 025959, But it also showing the middle values 100000, 132449. It should not show the middle values. Like this I need the Output

Comment: @Lieven: The Output should display Top and Bottom Cardeventtime according to the Cardeventdate, cardno. Middle Cardeventtime values should not show in the output according to the Cardeventdate, cardno

Comment: @Lieven: Please Go through my above 3 posted comment's you can easily understood, what exactly am expecting the output

Answer (score 5):

Well, unless you have some additional fields to establish an order, this is non deterministic. Given the three values for the 23-04-2009 - how is it that APPLE is the first and ROSE is the last? If the ID and the DATE are the same for all three entries, there's no order defined to filter out "GRAPHE"......

Marc

UPDATE: I expanded on Lieven's idea a bit and got this working in my setup:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
                          DayNumber INT, 
                          ID VARCHAR(3), DateField DATETIME, Value VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO @TempTable(DayNumber, id, datefield, value)
    SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DateField), ID, DateField, Value
    FROM @Table

SELECT * 
FROM @TempTable t
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT RowNumber = MIN(RowNumber), DayNumber, ID
    FROM @TempTable t
    GROUP BY DayNumber, t.ID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT MAX(RowNumber), DayNumber, ID
    FROM @TempTable t
    GROUP BY DayNumber, t.ID) t2 
  ON t2.RowNumber = t.RowNumber
GO
```

I'm basically creating a temp table with additional info - an artificial "RowNumber" to create some order, and the "DayNumber" to get dates grouped by date only (without time).

Seems to work ok for me - does it work for you, too?

Comment: Agreed and for this reason the table isn't even in 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

Jash, if you execute this script, does it give you the results you'd expect?

```
CREATE TABLE #T_Cardevent (CARDNO VARCHAR(3), CARDEVENTDATE VARCHAR(8), CARDEVENTTIME VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('121', '20090610', '025050')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('121', '20090611', '040000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('121', '20090611', '050000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('121', '20090611', '020000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('122', '20090611', '030001')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('122', '20090611', '030000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('123', '20090611', '080000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('123', '20090611', '100000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('123', '20090611', '132449')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('123', '20090611', '025959')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('124', '20090610', '030000')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('124', '20090612', '030001')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('125', '20090611', '030002')
INSERT INTO #T_Cardevent VALUES ('125', '20090612', '040000')

SELECT     
  RowNumber = IDENTITY (int, 1, 1)
  , CARDNO
  , CARDEVENTDATE
  , CARDEVENTTIME 
INTO #Table
FROM #T_CARDEVENT 

SELECT t1.CARDNO, t1.CARDEVENTDATE, t1.CARDEVENTTIME  
FROM #Table t1 
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT RowNumber = MIN(RowNumber), CARDEVENTDATE, CARDNO 
        FROM #Table t  
        GROUP BY cardno, cardeventdate  
        UNION ALL SELECT MAX(RowNumber), CARDEVENTDATE, CARDNO 
        FROM #Table t 
        GROUP BY cardno, cardeventdate) t2 ON t2.rownumber = t1.rownumber
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3

DROP TABLE #Table
DROP TABLE #T_Cardevent
```

Comment: also not sure if it works when the clustered index is not corresponding to the order the rows were inserted there.

Comment: @van: nice catch. I've updated the query. As for the clustered index, you are right and I've warned the OP about the non-deterministic execution of the query.

Comment: am using sub query's - id from one table and date and value from another table, from that how can i create a temp table?

Comment: INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Date, t2.Value
FROM (Table1Query) t1
     JOIN (Table2Query) t2 ON t1.Whatever=t2.Whatever.

Comment: Lieven, I understood, but am not using 7 column, am using n number of column, how can i insert all the n number of data's

Comment: @Jash. You do NOT need to create a temp table: Lieven just used it as a test for his query. You should only adapt his query to match your table and column names.

Comment: Am using sql server 2000 is not supporting the row number(), any function instead of row number()?

Comment: I would suggest you'd create a temporary table with an Identity column being the rownumber. You can then replace every ROW_NUMBER with this identity column.

Comment: @Jash, the response is adjusted to include a SQLServer 2000 example

Comment: @Lieven: I Go throgh the query, but i have to create a temp table for the row_number's. Suppose am using n number of column like day by day column is adding. so how i can create a temp table?

Comment: @Jash, I've separated the test data from the actual query doing the work. All you need to do is change the @Table reference in the SQL2000 example to your real tablename (or select)

Comment: @Lieven: while executing the query - 389902 row affected, so no error in the query, thank you, but nothing display in the output
How can i get a affected row data's?

Comment: @Jash: Add a SELECT * FROM #Table (before the DROP TABLE #Table )

Comment: @Lieven: GO Drop TABLE #Table is not executing showing error, without this query is executing successfully, how i have to delete a temp table

Comment: @Lieven, Row Number is Created for all column in the temp table, From that how can i select a id, date, top value and Bottom value from the temp table

Comment: @Jash, perhaps if you post your entire script you have up until now, we will be better equiped to help you. As it stands, the script I provided works as expected. I have no idea why it doesn't give any results at your end.

Comment: @Lieven, Don't me a mistake, am new to sql, your query is executing correctly. while executing this query, select * from temp table nothing output is displayed. That's y again i asked you? I don't know y nothing display in the output

Comment: @Jash, I'm sorry, without looking at your actual query, I have no clue as where to look for an error. Like I said, please post your query.

Comment: @Lieven: SELECT RowNumber = IDENTITY (int, 1, 1), Cardno, cardeventdate, Cardeventtime INTO #Table FROM T_Cardevent SELECT t1.CARDNO, t1.CARDEVENTDATE, t1.CARDEVENTIME FROM #Table t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT RowNumber = MIN(RowNumber), CARDEVENTDate, CARDNO FROM #Table t GROUP BY t .CARDEVENTDate, t .CARDNO UNION ALL SELECT MAX(RowNumber), CARDEVENTDate, CARDNO FROM #Table t GROUP BY t .CARDEVENTDate, t .CARDNO) t2 ON t2.CARDNO = t1.CARDNO AND t2.CARDEVENTDate = t1.CARDEVENTDate AND t2.RowNumber = t1.RowNumber

This is My original Query – Here am getting cardno, cardeventdate, cardeventtime

Comment: @Jash: I assume it should be CARDEVENTTIME. You missed one T.

Comment: @Lieven: cardno, cardeventdate, cardeventtime -> From this Query am selecting cardno, Cardeventdate, min time, max time. 
So Min Time and Max Time should take top column and botton column value for the particular date

Comment: @Lieven: Am not getting the First Time and Last time for the particular date, It's displaying all.

Comment: @Jash: I can only assure you that the testexamples you presented work with the queries presented here. If these queries don't allow you to get to the results you need, you'r better off launching a new, different formulated question instead of us trying to resolve this through comments. If you formulate a new question, make "sure" you give an accurate representation of data you are working with and what output you expect. The data you presented with this question obviously does not leed to the expected result.

Comment: @Lieven: I edited my question, Exactly what i need. Please go though and help me.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried it, but maybe something like this might do it:

```
SELECT TOP(1) FROM Table
WHERE Date='Some-date'
AND Id=Some-Id
ORDER BY Date ASC
UNION
SELECT TOP(1) FROM Table
WHERE Date='Some-date'
AND Id=Some-Id
ORDER BY Date Desc
```

Comment: Id - 001 to n, date - select this date  to  this date
For this condition, how can i make a query

Answer (score 0):

to cheat you can add an autonumber feild
AUtoID ID  DATE        VALUE
1 001 23:04:2009  APPLE
2 001 23:04:2009  GRAPHE
3 001 23:04:2009  ROSE
4 001 24:04:2009  BERRY
5 001 24:04:2009  TIFFANY
6 001 24:04:2009  ORGANE
7 001 24:04:2009  SILVER

You can then do min and max against it

I usually use insert into a tempory table which is defined with the ID, technically the insertion order isn't garenteed going in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using inline views:

```
with 
tempFirst as (
    select id, date, value, 
     row_number() over (partition by id, date order by date asc) as rownum1
    from table1
),
tempLast as ( 
    select *, 
     row_number() over (partition by id, date order by rownum1 desc) as rownum2 
    from tempFirst
)
select id, date, value from tempFirst where rownum1 = 1
union
select id, date, value from tempLast where rownum2 = 1
```

I have tested the output, which is:

```
ID  DATE       VALUE
001 2009-04-23 APPLE
001 2009-04-23 ROSE
001 2009-04-24 BERRY
001 2009-04-24 SILVER
```

Comment: While Executing the above query, it's showing error, Here i have start "with table" or select? Am using sub queries id from first table and date and value from second table. So I will work in sub queries?

Comment: You have to start from 'with tempFirst as .... rownum2 =1' ... I created a sample table with your values and tested on sqlserver. It gave me the desired result. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near "as" - showing error 
am using sql server 2000

Comment: WITH tempFirst AS (SELECT     cardno, cardeventdate, cardeventtime, row_number() OVER (partition BY cardno, cardeventdate ORDER BY cardeventdate ASC) AS rownum1 FROM  t_cardevent), tempLast AS
(SELECT     *, row_number() OVER (partition BY cardno, cardeventdate
ORDER BY rownum1 DESC) AS rownum2 FROM tempFirst) SELECT cardno, cardeventdate, cardeventtime FROM tempFirst WHERE rownum1 = 1
UNION SELECT     cardno, cardeventdate, cardeventtime FROM         tempLast WHERE     rownum2 = 1  From the above query,  it showing error in incorrect syntax nearn "as".

Comment: SQL 2000 doesnt support row_number(). I am using SQL 2005. I'll check if there is any work around for this.

Comment: @Rashmi: SQL 2000, How can i write a query for this condition

Comment: Doesn't Lieven's approach work for you? He has specifically mentioned SQL2000

Comment: Am Using Sub Queries, Identity is not accepting in sub query, 
See My Query
SELECT     T_PERSON.CARDNO, T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE AS CardEvenDateAdjusted, T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME FROM         (SELECT     RowNumber = IDENTITY (int, 1, 1), T_Person.CARDNO, .....) 

"While Executing this query it showing identity error".

Comment: @Rashmi: I edited my question, Exactly what i need. Please go through and help me